# How can I check Checkbutton value?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have a couple of checkboxes - created using dict and for loop. Everything seems to work just fine until I hit the "check" button. It seems that I don't know how to check the Checkbutton current value.

```
import random
from tkinter import *


def rolldice(dice):
    return random.randrange(1, dice, 1)


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Dices")
dices = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20]
check_box = {item: BooleanVar() for item in Dices}


def checkDices():
    if C == True:
        rolldice(item in Dices)
    else:
        print("end")


for item in Dices:
    C = Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=check_box[item], anchor=W, height=1, width=40)
    C.pack()

B1 = Button(root, text="Check", command=checkDices)
B1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to think about what `checkDices` do. What do you expect from the statement `if C == True`?

Comment: Okay, so checkDices in my world will go thru every Checkbutton I have (I know that the function itself is wrong - I tried to start with one and develop) and then if CheckbuttonValue is True/1 will run the text assigned to that Checkbutton thru rolldice function. Does it makes any sense?

Comment: Exactly. And how do you expect it to go through every CheckButton? Your variable `C` only binds to the last Checkbutton you created. What you need is to loop through your `check_box`, check if the BooleanVar is True, and then get the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want, maybe this code can help

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Dices")
Dices = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20]
check_box = {it: BooleanVar() for it in Dices}

def checkDices():
    for item in check_box:
        print(item,check_box[item].get())

for item in Dices:
    C = Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=check_box[item], anchor=W, height=1, width=40)
    C.pack()

B1 = Button(root, text="Check", command=checkDices)
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from tkinter import *


def rolldice(dice):
    return random.randrange(1, dice, 1)


def checkdices():
        for item in check_box:
            if check_box[item].get() == True:
                print("Dice", item, "K gave result -", rolldice(item))
            else:
                print("You didn't throw", item, "K dice")

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Dices")
dices = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20]
check_box = {item: BooleanVar() for item in dices}


for item in dices:
    C = Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=check_box[item], anchor=W, height=1, width=40)
    C.pack()

B1 = Button(root, text="Check", command=checkdices)
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks both of you for help. Henry - your question pointed the right direction - it was brilliant.